# Operations on rows in scipy sparse matrix of csr format

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I would like to multiply single rows of a csr matrix with a scalar. In numpy I would do

```
matrix[indices,:] = x * matrix[indices,:]
```

For csr this raises an exception in scipy.

Is there a way to do this similarily with csr matrixes?

Comment: Inefficient? On my SciPy 0.7.2, that raises an exception.

Comment: Sorry, I put it unclear. Edited.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there's no way to this directly, because although you can compute `row * x`, you can't assign to a row in a CSR matrix. You can either convert to DOK format and back, or work on the innards of the CSR matrix directly. The `i`'th row of a CSR matrix `X` is the slice

```
X.data[X.indptr[i] : X.indptr[i + 1]]
```

which you can update in-place, i.e.

```
X.data[X.indptr[i] : X.indptr[i + 1]] *= factor
```

(This obviously works for multiplication and other operations that preserve sparsity, but not things like addition.)